# Compare lists to retrieve object properties that don't match

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this linq query (successfully in most instances) to check one List against another List. The objective is to return the objects which have a `ThresholdType` not already included in the validThresholds list.

```
// Filter out thresholds previously added
manufacturerResult = (from r in validThresholds
                      from t in manufacturerLevel
                      where r.ThresholdType != t.ThresholdType
                      select t).ToList();
```

For some reason, which is really confusing me, I am getting a result of 20 objects. From comparing a list of possible 9 objects against a list of 3 valid objects.
Obviously I have made some error in the logic here, but I cannot see how I could get more results back than the sum of both collections! I am really interested to know why I am getting this result.

Originally I wanted to use a `Join` but that restricts me as it only allows the `equals` with no inequality operator.

Below I have created a sample application which recreates the issue.

```
public class ConsumableThreshold
{
    public int ThresholdType { get; set; }
    public int ThresholdValue { get; set; }

    public int ConsumableType { get; set; }
    public int ConsumableVariantID { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public int ModelID { get; set; }

}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DoWork();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            int manufacturerID = 4;


            ConsumableThreshold t1 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 0,
                ThresholdType       = 3,
                ThresholdValue      = 30
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t2 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 0,
                ThresholdType       = 2,
                ThresholdValue      = 50000
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t3 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 0,
                ThresholdType       = 6,
                ThresholdValue      = 3
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t4 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 2058,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 123,
                ThresholdType       = 3,
                ThresholdValue      = 31
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t5 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 3,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 0,
                ThresholdType       = 3,
                ThresholdValue      = 99
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t6 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 123,
                ThresholdType       = 3,
                ThresholdValue      = 25
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t7 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 123,
                ThresholdType       = 1,
                ThresholdValue      = 10
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t8 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 0,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 123,
                ThresholdType       = 4,
                ThresholdValue      = 15
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t9 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 3,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 0,
                ModelID             = 0,
                ThresholdType       = 3,
                ThresholdValue      = 1
            };
            ConsumableThreshold t10 = new ConsumableThreshold()
            {
                ConsumableType      = 2057,
                ConsumableVariantID = 0,
                ManufacturerID      = 4,
                ModelID             = 123,
                ThresholdType       = 3,
                ThresholdValue      = 32
            };


            List<ConsumableThreshold> groupThresholds = new List<ConsumableThreshold>()
            {
                t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10
            };

            List<ConsumableThreshold> validThresholds = new List<ConsumableThreshold>()
            {
                t5, t7, t8
            };

            List<ConsumableThreshold> manufacturerLevel =
                    (from t in groupThresholds
                     where t.ManufacturerID != 0 && t.ManufacturerID == manufacturerID
                     select t).ToList();

            if (manufacturerLevel.Count > 0)
            {
                List<ConsumableThreshold> manufacturerResult = new List<ConsumableThreshold>();

                if (validThresholds.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Filter out thresholds previously added
                    manufacturerResult = (from r in validThresholds
                                            from t in manufacturerLevel
                                            where r.ThresholdType != t.ThresholdType
                                            select t).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    manufacturerResult = manufacturerLevel;
                }

                validThresholds.AddRange(manufacturerResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I correctly compare two lists and return the objects where a specific property value does not exist in the other?

Comment: Do you only want items from one of these two lists, or from both?

Comment: My intent is to add the objects from `manufacturerLevel` to `validThresholds` where any object in `validThreshold` doesn't have the same ThresholdType value as any object in `manufacturerLevel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I correctly compare two lists and return the objects where a specific property value does not exist in the other?

Something like this?

```
manufacturerResult = (from t in manufacturerLevel
                      // where a specific property value does not exist in the other
                      where !validThresholds.Any(
                         r => r.ThresholdType == t.ThresholdType)
                      select t).ToList();
```

> My intent is to add the objects from manufacturerLevel to validThresholds where any object in validThreshold doesn't have the same ThresholdType value as any object in manufacturerLevel

```
validThresholds.AddRange(
    manufacturerLevel.Where(t => !validThresholds.Any(
                         r => r.ThresholdType == t.ThresholdType)));
```

You may also want to consider whether what you're really trying to do is compile a `Set` of these objects. If you made `validThresholds` a `HashSet<>`, for example, with an `IEqualityComparer<>` based on the `ThresholdType`, you could simply `Add` all the items, and it would automatically ignore any whose `ThresholdType` was already represented in the collection.

Comment: This is working for me. Do you know why my original solution was returning 20 objects? I'm curious to know where the logic fell short of the task.

Comment: @Amicable: Mais oui. Doing a double `from` is similar to a double `for` loop, or, in set-based terms, an Outer Join. You're producing each possible pair with one item from the first list and one from the second, where the two items don't have the same `ThresholdType`.

Comment: You're right about a hashset being preferable in my situation. My solution now utilises one with a comparer class similar to AD .Net's answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = manufacturerLevel.Where(t => !validThresholds.Any(t2 => t.ThresholdType == t2.ThresholdType));
```

EDIT:

> My intent is to add the objects from manufacturerLevel to validThresholds where any object in validThreshold doesn't have the same ThresholdType value as any object in manufacturerLevel

If I understood it correctliy you need to merge the two collections, right?

```
var validThresholds= validThresholds.Union(manufacturerLevel);
```

Make sure you override properly the `Equals`method in `ConsumableThreshold`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this, you can have your custom comparer to determine if an object is different from another, and then just use .Except on the collection of those objects.

```
public class ConsumableThreshold : IEqualityComparer<ConsumableThreshold>
    {
        public int ThresholdType { get; set; }
        public int ThresholdValue { get; set; }

        public int ConsumableType { get; set; }
        public int ConsumableVariantID { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
        public int ModelID { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(ConsumableThreshold x, ConsumableThreshold y)
        {
            return x.ThresholdType == y.ThresholdType;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ConsumableThreshold obj)
        {
            return obj.ThresholdType.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And then get the difference like this:

```
var diff = groupThresholds.Except(validThresholds).ToList();
```